# Looping Cross-Validation

Tags: python, cross-validation

I am trying to loop the process of cross-validation for different models.

```
         models=[LogisticRegression(),DecisionTreeClassifier()]
         score=[]
         for i in models:
              model=i
              model.fit(X_train,y_train)
              pred=model.predict(X_test)
              score.append(accuracy_score(y_test,pred))
```

When i try to do the same thing but add cross-val-score as the last step I always get an error!

```
          models=[LogisticRegression(),DecisionTreeClassifier()]
          score=[]
          for i in models:
                model=i
                model.fit(X_train,y_train)
                cross=cross_val_score(model,X_train,y_train,cv=5,n_jobs=-1)
                score.append(cross.mean())
```

This always throws an error of 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable

Full Error:

```
           ------------------------------------------------------------------
           TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent 
           call last)
           <ipython-input-81-a1938b7ef631> in <module>
           model=i
           model.fit(X_train,y_train)
       ---->cross=cross_val_score(model,X_train,y_train,cv=5,n_jobs=-1)
           score.append(corss.mean())
```

TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable

Comment: What is `cross_val_score` and why are you calling it? Did you mean to call something *on* it?

Comment: Don't forget to include the full error traceback in your question

Comment: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_score.html

Comment: @NitinKumar GreenCloakGuy points you seem to define a variable with the same name